# Find if 2 element are in the same sublist

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sublist

I have 2 lists of words,

```
list1 = ['hello', 'world']
list2 = ['hi']
```

and a sublist list like

```
GROUPS = [['hello','good'], ['hello', 'hi', 'etc'], ['hi', 'world', 't']]
```

What is the fastest (or least code) way to find if every couple of words of list1 and list2 is in a sublist? Finding and counting them.

I used this but I'm searching for a better way if it exists:

```
found = 0
list_couples = []
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        for gr in GROUPS:
            if a in gr and b in gr:
                found += 1
                list_couples.append((a, b))
                break
```

I would like to get `found = 2` and a couple like `[('hello','hi'), ('world', hi')]`.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest is likely the following, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), [`set.issuperset`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issuperset.html), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
from itertools import product

couples = []
for gr in map(set, GROUPS):  # make sets for O(1) contains-check
    pair = next((p for  p in product(list1, list2) if gr.issuperset(p)), None)
    if pair:
        couples.append(p)
found = len(couples)
```

This iterates over the *set*-cast `groups` and - for each - collects the *next* best pair of the cartesian *product* of `list1` and `list2` for which the group is *superset* - if it exists.

Note that this is very performant as `product` and `map` create lazy iterators and `next` breaks early on the first hit, so there is no over-generation of pairs.

Comment: `groups` doesn't need to be a list since you're just iterating over it: `groups = map(set, GROUPS)`

Comment: @wjandrea I relized that, too, but was making a bunch of changes to collect the couples and not just count them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html) with [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from the `itertools` module:

```py
from itertools import product

list_couples = []

for gr in GROUPS:
    list_couples.extend([(x[0], x[1]) for x in product(list1, list2) if x[0] in gr and x[1] in gr])
found = len(list_couples)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ['hello', 'world']
list2 = ['hi']
GROUPS = [['hello','good'], ['hello', 'hi', 'etc'], ['hi', 'world', 't']]
result = [i for i in product(list1, list2) if list(filter(lambda x: i[0] in x and i[1] in x ,GROUPS))]
found = len(result)
```

That will check all the options in list1 and list2 if they exist in one of the GROUPS lists.

Comment: `list(filter(lambda`? ew. Use a comprehension instead, also use `any` instead of checking the truthiness of a list, and `product` doesn't need to be cast to a list: `[i for i in product(list1, list2) if any(i[0] in x and i[1] in x for x in GROUPS)]`